# MongoDB, remote connection failing

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongoDB server running in another AWS Account from my other AWS account to refresh the content.
I'm getting an error.

```
 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer mongo_db_server:27017
I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [mongodb_db_server:27017]
2021-01-14T23:26:26.015-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'mongodb_db_server:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
@(connect):1:6
```

Remote MongoDB server config has

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Security groups allow connection to 27017 from 0.0.0.0/0 fo testing purpose.

what am i missing?

Comment: Is the database running?

Comment: Yes. I can connect to it from an instance that running in the same account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to network connectivity.